# getting prompt and saving it as object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm getting confused in following javascript.
In the following code, the read method is prompting a value from user and saving it as object properties.

```
let calculator = {
  sum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  },

  mul() {
    return this.a * this.b;
  },

  read() {
    this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
    this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
  }
};

calculator.read();
alert( calculator.sum() );
alert( calculator.mul() );
```

But when i do console.log(calculator.a);, the result is undefined.
Why is it happening? Is the read method really saving the prompt as object properties or something else is happening?
Please help

Comment: Are you doing `console.log(calculator.a)` before calling `calculator.read()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but not when you at first log `this.a/b` - because both are not yet initialized. So, when you log *after* a read, the values will be displayed.

```js
let calculator = { 
  sum() { return this.a + this.b; },
  mul() { return this.a * this.b; },
  read() {
    this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
    this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
  }
};

calculator.read();
alert( calculator.sum() );
alert( calculator.mul() );
console.log(calculator.a);
```

Prompts and alerts are really annoying. Let's offer an alternative, using two number fields, an `input` handler ([event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)) and a factory function to avoid the use of `this` and to be able to associate a calculator to two input elements:

```js
document.addEventListener(`input`, handle);

const calculatorFactory = (a = 0, b = 0, elemA, elemB) => {
  elemA.value = a;
  elemB.value = b;
  
  return {
    read: () => {
      a = +elemA.value || 0;
      b = +elemB.value || 0; },
    get sum() {return a + b; },
    get mul() {return a * b; },
    get a() { return a; },
    get b() { return b; },
  };
};

const calculator = calculatorFactory(10, 5, 
  document.querySelector(`#valA`), 
  document.querySelector(`#valB`) );
  
getResult(calculator);

function getResult(calculator) {
    calculator.read();
    console.clear();
    console.log(`calculator.a = ${calculator.a}`);
    document.querySelector(`#aValue`).textContent = calculator.sum;
    return document.querySelector(`#bValue`).textContent = calculator.mul;
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (/valA|valB/.test(evt.target.id)) {
    return getResult(calculator);
  }
}
```

```css
#aValue:before {
  content: 'Sum: ';
}

#bValue:before {
  content: 'Multiplied: ';
}

#AB:before {
  content: 'Values: ';
}
```

```html
<input id="valA" type="number"> value a
<input id="valB" type="number"> value b

<div>
  <div id="aValue"></div>
  <div id="bValue"></div>
</div>
```